# Jquery mobile dynamic selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile 1.4.0 rc1 with Chrome 31.

I've got the following html code

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="first">First:</label>
    <select name="first" id="first" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="" data-place-holder="true">Choose...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

with the following jquery section

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $('#first').on("change", function () {
        console.log("change");
        $("#second").html("<select name='cr_prptpl:400002' id='cr_prptpl:400002' data-native-menu='false'><option value='' data-placeholder='true'>&lt;Null&gt;</option><option value='2003'>2003</option><option value='2008' selected>2008</option><option value='2012'>2012</option></select>");
        $("select").selectmenu();
    });
});
```

But it seems that the trigger is not responding unless I'm removing the "pageinit" event.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Qph4/

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5Qph4/1/ select _No wrap - in <head>_ option in jsfiddle when dealing with page events.

Comment: Thanks @Omar. jsfiddle works okay. Tried with my site but still have some problems. Any idea why after `enhanceWithin()` or `selectmenu()` the code is being generated as here [link]http://jsfiddle.net/w2Ec5/1/ ?

Comment: when setting `data-native-menu` to `false`, jQM converts selectmenu into a popup (few options) or a dialog (more options). in your website try binding `pageinit` to page `$(document).on("pageinit", "#page_id", function () {`

Comment: It is bind as `$(document).on("pageinit", "#form1", function (event) {` where `form1` is the ID of the form, but when I set `data-native-menu` to `false` the drop box is not being opened.
 `data-native-menu` on `true` works alright.

Comment: You cant bind `pageinit` or any page event to elements except page div.

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that colon `:` character on the id makes some troubles, because it's a meta-character.

Comment: Yes, thanks.
Not sure why when I bind dynamic content with elements containing meta-characters on the ID I have issues where on static elements with meta-characters everything works alright.

Comment: bind events of dynamic items this way `$(document).on("event", "#ID", function () {`